# Proof that $f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)\sin(x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2}$ is differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, continuity

Consider the function

$$f(x,y) =(x^2 + y^2)\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)$$

The partial derivative with respect to $x$ are equal to

> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) =\left\{\begin{array}  \\
> 0 &\text{ if $x = 0, y = 0$ } \\
> 2x \sin(1/|x|) - sign(x)\cos(1/|x|) & \text{ if $x \ne 0, y = 0$} \\
> \cos \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} &\text{ if $x \ne 0,y \ne 0$}
> \end{array} \right\}$$
>   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y) =\left\{\begin{array}  \\
> 0 &\text{ if $x = 0, y = 0$ } \\
> 2y \sin(1/|y|) - sign(y)\cos(1/|y|) & \text{ if $x = 0, y \ne 0$} \\
> \cos \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} &\text{ if $x \ne 0,y \ne 0$}
> \end{array} \right\}$$

I've heard that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable even though the partial derivatives are not continuous.

However, the sources I've seen don't prove that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable. In fact, they just [point out](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~rogness/mathlets/partialsNotContDiff.html) (very misleadingly) that the partial derivatives are equal to zero at $(0,0)$, which is not [enough for a function to be differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2569740) at $(0,0)$.

> **Question** How do I prove that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Hint: Try polar coordinates.

Comment: The function here is not differentiable (nor do $f_x(0,0)$ or $f_y(0,0)$ exist). The source you cite probably meant it to be $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}$.

Comment: Thank you Poon, the source was indeed wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only point of contention is $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

We have $| f(x,y) - f(0,0)  - 0 (x,y)| \le \|(x,y)\|^2$, hence
the Frechet derivative is zero (the zero linear mapping).