# Questions about real differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian

Let $f$ be $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

What I recall/understand:

1. That $f$ is *differentiable* at a point $(a,b)$ is defined as this weird thing from James Stewart, Calculus (similar for $v$)

[image]

2. Sufficient condition: That $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable a point $(a,b)$ has a sufficient condition from this theorem also from James Stewart, Calculus

[image]

which I read as

> If $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist *in an open disc containing* $(a,b)$ and are continuous at $(a,b)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$.

---

Questions:

1. Does $f$ differentiable at $(a,b)$ imply $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist at $(a,b)$?
2. For $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ differentiable at $(a,b)$, what exactly its 'derivative' anyway?

- **Update**: It's Jacobian. The thing is [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions) doesn't say the jacobian  of $f$ is the derivative of $f$. Anyway, I'll tag this question with jacobian.

  - What I understand is for just $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, we have $g$ 'differentiable' at $a$ if $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$ exists and then define the 'derivative' $g'(x)$ as the limit. Similar for even complex derivative, for example.

So what about for $f$? What is the 'derivative' of $f$? You might argue that $f$ doesn't really have 'a'/'the' derivative but rather has infinite derivatives, eg using gradient based on $f_x$ and $f_y$.

But even for just $f_x$ and $f_y$ these derivatives exist based on the existence of a limit. Like you could define something like 'differentiable in the $x$-direction at $(a,b)$' if $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x,b)-f(a,b)}{x-a}$ exists and then you define 'the derivative in the $x$-direction at $(a,b)$' as the limit.

So, what, differentiable for $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ doesn't really have like 'a derivative' ?

Comment: 1. is true but not its reciprocal see -> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569710/a-function-whose-partial-derivatives-exist-at-a-point-but-is-not-continuous

Comment: @zwim thanks. as for why the reciprocal (converse?) is false...well that's the whole point of sufficient condition right? i don't know any explicit counter-example, but i just find it weird if a book will call it sufficient condition instead of equivalent condition, if they're actually equivalent...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definition of *derivative* of a function $f$ from $\mathbf{R}^m$ to $\mathbf{R}^n$ at a point $x \in \mathbf{R}^m$ is that it is the linear map that approximates $f$ to order greater than one near $x$. Precisely, a linear map $L:\mathbf{R}^m \to \mathbf{R}^n$ is the derivative of $f$ at $x$ provided

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-L(h)}{|h|}=0,$$ where $h$ is a vector in $\mathbf{R}^m$ tending towards $0$ and $|h|$ denotes its length. If you define the quantity in the limit as $\epsilon(h)$, then this is the same as saying that
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+L(h)+|h| \epsilon(h),$$ where $\epsilon(h)$ goes to $0$ with $h$ (in this sense $L$ approximates $f$ to order greater than $1$). Moreover if a linear map with this property exists, it is unique.

This is what the first definition you mention is saying (in coordinates, and with $m=2$ and $n=1$). But you are right that you could also define directional derivatives: for a vector $v$ you could put
$$\partial_v(f)(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h}$$ where $h$ now runs over $\mathbf{R}$, when this limit exists and call it the *derivative of $f$ in the direction $v$*. The relationship between these is that if $f$ has a derivative in the first sense, it has derivatives in all directions $v$ and
$$\partial_v(f)(x)=L(v).$$

Conversely, the last assertion is that if the derivatives in the directions $v_1,\dots,v_m$ exist in a neighborhood of $x$ and are continuous at $x$, where $v_1,\dots,v_m$ is a basis of $\mathbf{R}^m$, then $f$ has a derivative $L$ in the first sense. All this is completely standard and can be found, for instance, in Spivak's nice book *Calculus on manifolds*.

Comment: wait so jacobian is the derivative? it seems your $L$ is the same as $J$ in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions), but i didn't see anything in wiki like $J$ is the 'derivative' of $f$. thanks Stephen

Comment: I usually prefer to just call $L$ the *derivative*, as distinct from the *Jacobian matrix* and especially the *Jacobian determinant*, which sometimes people shorten to *Jacobian*. But yes, the Jacobian matrix as defined at your link is the matrix of the derivative with respect to the canonical bases of $\mathbf{R}^m$ and $\mathbf{R}^n$.

Comment: ...and for reasonable functions, the columns of the Jacobian matrix are the directional derivatives corresponding to the canonical basis (the *partial derivatives* of $f$).

Comment: anyway, that settles Q2. thanks Stephen. as for Q1, your answer is 'The relationship between these is that if f has a derivative in the first sense, it has derivatives in all directions' right?

Comment: Right! And the best you can say for the converse is that if the derivatives in all directions are well-defined in a neighborhood of your point and continuous at it, then it has a derivative in the first sense whose matrix is given by them in the way I mentioned above.

Comment: thanks Stephen. damn wiki. lol.

Comment: re 'All this is completely standard and can be found, for instance, in Spivak's nice book Calculus on manifolds.' oh i see. i was able to find it just now in my real analysis textbook. i'll just blame wiki because they didn't call jacobian the derivative of f and forget about my own stupidity of not checking my real analysis textbook. lol. btw i also hate to use the term just 'jacobian'. always jacobian matrix or jacobian determinant. hey i have a weird idea: do you want to call L the Jacobian derivative?

Comment: Stephen, do you know how all this relates to [complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289188/difference-comparison-relation-of-real-differentiable-vs-complex-differentiable) please?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Sure, I just posted an answer there! I hope it helps.