# Why are the remainder terms smooth in Tu's Manifold Lemma 1.4?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

[image]

I'm trying to start learning about manifold through [Loring Tu's book](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Ejeffrey/matd67/tu.pdf). However, the first result has me somewhat confused. I was for the most part able to follow Lemma 1.4 which proves Taylor's theorem with remainder. However, I am confused as to how Tu was able to easily conclude $g_i(x)$ is in $C^\infty(U)$. Looking at its definition (see picture), it isn't clear to me why this is immediate true. The outer integral "blocking" the smooth function $f$ is what concerns me.

I am convinced from equation 1.1
$$
f(x) = f(p) + \sum (x^i - p^i) g_i(x)
$$
that the mixed partials of $g_i(x)$ must exist otherwise $f$ would not be in $C^\infty$. But, why must these mixed partials be continuous over $U$? After all, [aren't there examples of partials existing at a point while not being continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569710/a-function-whose-partial-derivatives-exist-at-a-point-but-is-not-continuous)?

Comment: In this context, ask yourself what it means for $f$ to be in $C^{\infty}.$

Comment: Just as a rule of thumb, integration makes things more smooth, not less. What is inside the integration is smooth because $f\in C^\infty$, and no integration is going to ruin that. You can find the relevant theorems in pretty much any Intro to Real Analysis textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I convinced myself that $g_i(x)$ is in fact in $C^\infty$ over $U$. The basic strategy I used involved first thinking about $\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x^j}(x)$ which by Leibniz integral rule is $\int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j \partial x^i}(p + t(x-p))dt$. Because $f$ is in $C^\infty$ over $U$, the integrand is also in $C^\infty$ over $U$. By repeatedly taking partial derivatives of $g_i$ and using Leibniz rule, we get a function of the form $G(x) = \int_0^1 F(p + t(x-p))dt$ where $F$ is in $C^\infty$ over $U$. By showing that $G(x)$ is continuous over $U$, it would effectively be proven that $g_i$ and all its mixed partials exist and are continuous over $U$.

Consider forming a closed box $B = [a_1, a_1'] \times \ldots \times [a_n, a_n']$ around $x \in U$, which exists as $U$ is open. Then form a "cone" $K = \{p + \lambda(b - p) \vert b \in B, \lambda \in [0,1]\}$ which lies entirely in $U$ as $U$ is star-shaped. The set $K$ is closed and bounded and thus compact. Because $F$ is continuous over $U$, $F$ is continuous over the compact set $K \subseteq U$ and is thus uniformly continuous over $K$.

Uniform continuity over $K$ implies that
$$
\begin{align*}
| G(x + \Delta x) - G(x) | &= \left \vert \int_0^1 F(p + t(x + \Delta x - p)) - F(p + t(x - p)) dt \right \vert \\
&\leq \int_0^1 | F(p + t(x + \Delta x - p)) - F(p + t(x - p))| dt
\end{align*}
$$
can be made arbitrarily small so long as $\Delta x$ has sufficiently small length proving continuity at $x$.